# Magento cron job disappearing

Tags: cron

I'm having a problem with Magento 1 cron job. AoE scheduler and logs show the same error:

> Host has not been available for a while now to update the status of
>   this task and the task is not reporting back by itself

There are no errors in the code... Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Seen the same issue and I fix it by increasing PHP memory limit

Comment: Sorry for mark as commentary answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This error comes as a result of Aoe_Scheduler. Firstly try upgrading it, if that doesn't remove the error then perhaps you should remove it all together.

I found there was a conversation about it on the issues for Aoe_Scheduler but it never got solved : https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/issues/218

Removing the module should solve your problem, or at least expose the true error.